# How to configure node and komodo ide?

Tags: node.js, komodo

i am trying to configure node.exe with komodo ide 10.2.

i have few asks :

Can i use  Ctrl+s or other keys shortcut of the keyboard, to re-launch node interpreter to open/refresh the result of output in the web browser of a komdo's tab ?

For the moment i just did : **Language** -> **Node.js**->**Default Node.js interpreter** ->**use this interpreter** in this field i set c:\node.exe

Do I have to configure some others preferences fields?

Must i configure the field in **Debugger** ->**Connection** ->**Komodo should listen for debugging connections on :**->**a specific port** ? i set here **8080** ;

Must i check "I am running a debugger proxy and Komodo should use it"?

Must i configure a server in **Servers** and after configuer something in **Mapped URIs**??

or must i use a tool as **supervisor** with **npm installer**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Komodo currently does not reload the browser preview when you save a file, you could use [livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload) to facilitate that.

The debugging port is only used when you use [remote debugging](http://docs.komodoide.com/Manual/debugnode#debugging-node-komodo-ide-only_debugging-node-remotely), you do not need it for local debugging. You "must" not check anything, it depends on what you are doing. Most likely you do not need to use a debugger proxy for your use case.

You do not need to configure a server for debugging. Mapped URIs are useful if you are remote debugging, for local debugging you shouldn't need it.

I would suggest you read the [Debugging Node documentation](http://docs.komodoide.com/Manual/debugnode).